how to get the supporting points of flexible curve in catia vba
I am trying to create macro that can pull the information of supporting points list of flexible curve.
and I have no idea how to proceed with.
Dim oDoc As Document
Set oDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim oProds 'As item
Set oProds = oDoc.Product.Products.Item(1).ReferenceProduct.Parent.part.hybridBodies

Dim my1
Set my1 = oPro.Item(5).HybridShapes

Dim my2    
Set my2 = my1.Item(1).refernce

for i = 1 to my2.count

debug.print my2.name

next 

any suggestions would be appreciative.

Which type does teh flexible curve_ has? Please show from which element and how you display the typename. If you could not get a type, i guess you can also not get the points.

'Sub CATMain()
Dim oDoc As ProductDocument
Set oDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Dim oProds 'As item
Set oProds = oDoc.Product.Products.Item(1).ReferenceProduct.Parent.part.hybridBodies
Dim my1
Set my1 = oProds.Item(5).HybridShapes
Dim my2
Set my2 = my1.Item(1)
Dim mycurve 'As Object
Set mycurve = my2.Parent.Item(1)
Debug.Print mycurve.Value.TypeName
End Sub'  i am unable to get type name

What's the type of my2? (this should be the flexible curve)

Set my2 = my1.Item(1).Value.TypeName  // Set my2 = my1.Item(1).Value.Type  //Set my2 = my1.Item(1).TypeName i have tried this combination no result.

Try TypeName(my2) (or select the curve and use TypeName(Catia.ActiveDocument.Selection.Item2(1).Value)

it is showing  type as "HybridShapeSpline"

So you can check the documentation for this object to find possible methods to get the points (e.g. GetPointPosition or GetPoint).

Set myname = selection1.Item(1).Value /  Debug.Print myname.GetNbControlPoint , with this i can get the number of points that can supporting. but i am not able to get the points name can you please help me on this format type .i tried with For i = 1 To myname.GetNbControlPoint
Dim mypoints
Set mypoints = myname.GetPoint.Item(i)
Debug.Print mypoints.name
Next

The following example shows how to loop over the control points of a spline
Sub CATMain()

Dim oPartDoc As PartDocument
Dim oPart As Part
Dim oHybridBody As HybridBody
Dim oSpline As HybridShapeSpline
Dim i As Integer

Set oPartDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set oPart = oPartDoc.Part
Set oHybridBody = oPart.HybridBodies.Item(1)
Set oSpline = oHybridBody.HybridShapes.Item("Spline.1")

For i = 1 To oSpline.GetNbControlPoint
    Debug.Print oSpline.GetPoint(i).DisplayName
Next

End Sub

